# c++ attempting to reference a deleted function in non existing constructor (using rapidJson)

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I'm currently getting this error:
**'User::User(const User&)': attempting to reference a deleted function**

The program passes a string value of an object into the class.

User Constructor:

```
User::User(string s){
    int size = s.length() + 1;
    char* cstr = new char[size];
    strcpy_s(cstr, size, s.c_str());
    user.Parse(cstr);
}
```

Main Loop:

```
int main(){
    //json equals something similar to this: "{\"body:{[{"user":1},{"user":1},{"user":1}]}\"}";
    const char * json;
    Document d;
    d.Parse(json);
    if (d.HasMember("body")) {
        if (d["body"].IsArray()) {
            for (SizeType i = 0; i < d["body"].Size(); i++) {
                string json = getJsonString(d["body"][i]);
                User u = User(json); \\this is where the error point to
                this->users.push_back(u);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

getJsonString function:

```
string getJsonString(Value& value) {
    StringBuffer buffer;
    buffer.Clear();
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
    value.Accept(writer);
    return string(buffer.GetString());
}
```

I search for a lot of explanation on this error but nothing seems to make sense to me. I think it has something to do with the vector array however it doesn't make sense to me as I'm not using a pointer or reference for any of the user value. It seems to point to the constructor however no pointer or reference is being passed through. I through by returning the string of the json, I wasn't using a pointer but maybe I actually am? I would be grateful for any explanation to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please show the `User` *class definition*. You have something in it that makes the compiler auto-generate a deleted copy-constructor (or you did it yourself?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`User` is not copyable; this means that:

- `User::User(const User&)` (copy constructor) is `private`
- or deleted (`= delete;`)
- or deleted implicitly (e.g. class has non-copyable members, or inherits from a non-copyable class). Thank you Yksisarvinen for the comment

This means you are not allowed to create a new `User` from another one.

Then, if you want to store `User` objects in a `vector` (as you are "apparently" trying to do in your post, I say "apparently" because the posted code does not compile, I dunno who is `this`) you cannot store them by value, as the `vector` contained needs an accessible copy constructor.

See [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

> `T` must meet the requirements of `CopyAssignable` and `CopyConstructible`.

However, you can store them as pointers:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<User>> users;
users.push_back( std::shared_ptr<User>( new User( json ) );
```

Comment: Created a copy constructor and it worked. Thank you